# Execute Python Script With Parse Arguments From C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

as you can see in the pictures above i am trying to execute a python script which returns me recommended movies the inputs that python script is waiting for are the following:

--movie_name "Iron Man" --top_n 10      1) accepted way from python

"--movie_name" "Iron Man" "--top_n" "10" 2) accepted way from python

The last hours im searching for a way to give them properly but i cant. You can see in picture my last attempt.[Image from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaWta.png), 
[Image from vsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yK3B.png)

```
        string s = "\"Iron Man\"";
        string s1 = "\" --movie_name\"";
        string s2 = "\" --top_n \"";
        string s3 = "\"10\"";

        string arg = string.Format(@"\c C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py {0} {1} {2} {3}", s1, s, s2, s3);

        try
        {
            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = arg;
            p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe ", arg);
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.Start();
            p1.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a problem in your Python code: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Instead of uploading screenshots I would suggest copying and pasting the code you want to share.

Comment: your string now is this ```\c C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py " --movie_name" "Iron Man" " --top_n " "10"```  but you need this  ```/c C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py --movie_name "Iron Man" --top_n 10 ``` so the only extra ```\"``` are needed araound the movie name "s", so s is OK now.

Comment: the call of the command should start with ```/c``` not "\c". consider string arg = string.Format(@"/c \"C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py\" {0} {1} {2} {3}", s1, s, s2, s3);

Comment: @ralf.w. nah if i put "\"s\"" it will take s as string, i tried also "\"Iron Man\"" and didn't work..

Comment: @ralf.w. The path that im giving is correct, the arguments are in wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, and is the following.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

string s1 = "--movie_name";
string s2 = "\"Iron Man\"";
string s3 = "--top_n";
string s4 = "10";

process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe ", @"/c C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py " + s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s4)
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas"
};
process.Start();

string res = "";
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
while (!process.HasExited)
{
    q.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()); 
}
string r = q.ToString();
res = r;
Console.Write("RESULTS: " + res.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

just try these first lines instead:

```
    string s = "Iron Man";
    string s1 = "--movie_name";
    string s2 = "--top_n";
    string s3 = "10";

    string arg = string.Format(@"/c ""C:\Users\Azizmaiden\Desktop\files\hello\KnnRecommender.py"" {0} ""{1}"" {2} {3}", s1, s, s2, s3);
```

All argument names itself like --movie_name have to be without "
Your movie name has to be sorrounded by ", which is easier to read inside your format.
If your KnnRecommender.py file ever ends up in a path containing a space, you have to surround it with " anyways.

Comment: it gives me compile error in path, the way u wrote it. i tried every combination nothing seems to work..

Comment: @azizmaiden : sorry, I didn't see that "@". code is changed now.